# How to pass boolean from one function to another

Tags: c++, qt, boolean

I have a program where in function 1 I want to send a boolean value to another function.

Function 1

```
bool Widget::openFile(){

fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                             "Choose Software File",
                                             "C://",
                                             tr("BIN(*.bin);; All files(*.*)")
                                             );

bool fileExists = QFile::exists(fileName);

return fileExists;
```

Even if bool is "true" I always get false in function 2.

Function 2

```
void Widget::on_downloadButton_clicked(bool fileExists)
{
 if (fileExists){

        qDebug() << "there is a file";

    }
    else{

        qDebug() << "there is no file!";

    }
}
```

No matter what I do I ALWAYS get "there is no file" in function 2. Why is this?

I am expecting to get the same boolean value in Function 2 that is being set in Function 1.

Comment: The local variable in function 1 and the function parameter of function 2 are completely separate variables. You'd actually need to call the second function from the first one (`on_downloadButton_clicked(QFile::exists(fileName));`) or store the data in some field (this would require the functions to be called in the correct order though).

Comment: Please show how the functions are called. Your code should be complete enough for someone to copy-compile-run your code to reproduce your result (a.k.a. a [mre]). In this case, if `Widget` is a class (rather than a namespace), it might be helpful to move the functions outside the class; make them free functions instead of member functions. Then create a `main` function to simulate the calls -- are you expecting the calls to be independent, as in `openFile(); on_downloadButton_clicked(false);` or related, as in `on_downloadButton_clicked(openFile());`?

Answer (score 1):

```
   void Widget::on_downloadButton_clicked()
{
 if (openFile()){//call here bool function

        qDebug() << "there is a file";

    }
    else{

        qDebug() << "there is no file!";

    }
}
```

you can try to call bool function in if statment

Comment: Hello, thanks for replies, what I did do is put the bool fileExists = false; variable in header file private.

Comment: then why you redefinate bool fileExist in your first function

Comment: It doesn't get redefined anymore, I have changed my approach.